# "The camera is in use. Close any applications using it and try again. in Blackberry Z10 when invoking the camera in Blackberry 10 Cascades

Tags: c++, qt, camera, qml, blackberry-10

I am using Blackberry 10 Cascades (C++, QT & QML), and I am trying to invoke the camera on a physical Blackberry Z 10, but when I do so I am getting the error, "The camera is in use. Close any applications using it and try again. in Blackberry Z10 when invoking the camera in Blackberry 10 Cascades.", but I can't find any other apps that are using the camera as opened, including the camera.  Is there a way I can check all apps that are running, including hidden ones?  And close all other running apps (hidden or not - both manually & programatically)?

My code to start the camera looks like this:

```
InvokeManager manager;
InvokeRequest request;
request.setTarget("sys.camera.card");
request.setAction("bb.action.CAPTURE");
request.setMimeType("image/jpeg");
InvokeTargetReply *reply = manager.invoke(request);
```

Or is/are there some other solution(s) to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the camera capability requested in your xml file?

i.e., in config.xml

```
<rim:permissions>
    <rim:permit>use_camera</rim:permit>
</rim:permissions>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to the debugger in Momentics you'll be able to see all the running processes. It may be that a process has not been slayed and is holding the camera open so other apps cannot use it. Hard resetting (hold down power+volup+voldown for 10 seconds) will solve this issue.